# Active load and current source purpose on NE5532

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, jfet, bipolar, active-components

I'm trying to do some reverse engineering on the NE5532 schematic, but I can't understand how is designed the current source for the first stage. What I want to analyze now is in yellow on the picture. As I understand, the first differential amplifier is polarized with a Widlar current source(Q1-Q3), but what I'd like to know if someone can figure out:

- The purpose of Q2. Having another widlar source? But why would we need that?
- The purpose of the active load Q4-Q5 and the transistor Q7. Why the reference transistor Q3 isn't just plugged with a resistor directly to VCC to generate the reference current?
- What's the purpose of the branch of the JFET (Q6-Q8)?[image]

Comment: Here you have the early version of this circuit. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGnz3.jpg The Q1, Q2 ,Q4, Q5 are the current mirror + bandgap reference. And Q6, Q8 is a start-up circuits for the bandgap reference. I guess.